# How may I reformat this to use more composition instead of all inheritance?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization

I'm learning inheritance and composition in C# for the first time and based on the below so far, is there a cleaner/more modular way I could restructure my code by implementing composition for my 2d platformer game? I'd like to bring in composition before the game gets too big.

To give some context (I know this is a separate issue), I'm also in the middle of trying to figure out a way that only the enemy gets damaged when the player jumps on top of the enemy and so the player does not get damaged. I have two colliders on the enemy (image below) and I was also messing around with OverlapArea(). I'm not really sure how to go about this.

[Enemy with a collider on top to receive damage and one below to deal damage to player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUWtT.png)

Base class:

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour {
    public int maxHealth;
    public int currentHealth;
    public HealthBar healthBar;

    [SerializeField] protected float damageInterval = 2f; //in seconds
    protected float currentDamageInterval;

    protected SpriteRenderer sr;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    protected virtual void Start() {
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        healthBar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
    }
    protected virtual void Update() {
        //subtract 1 real life second
        if (currentDamageInterval >= 0)
            currentDamageInterval -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    public bool CanTakeDamage() {
        return (currentDamageInterval < 0);
    }
    public virtual void TakeDamage(int damage) {
        currentHealth -= damage;
        healthBar.SetHealth(currentHealth);
        int yDamageVelocity = 15;

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, yDamageVelocity);
        //set currentDamageInterval to start a new cooldown/delay period (2 seconds)
        currentDamageInterval = damageInterval;
    }
}
```

Children classes:

```
public class Player : Character {
    [SerializeField] private Transform groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask hazardLayer;
    private Color[] colors = { Color.red, Color.white };
    private Coroutine damageFlash;
    protected override void Start() {
        base.Start();
        maxHealth = 10;
    }
    protected override void Update() {
        base.Update();
        //if the current number in the currentDamageInterval is <= 0 or in other words if
        //2 seconds of delay has passed, take damage
        if (CanTakeDamage())
            if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.5f, hazardLayer)) {
                TakeDamage(1);
            }
        //for testing purposes
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.H))
            TakeDamage(1);
    }
    public override void TakeDamage(int damage) {
        base.TakeDamage(damage);
        //guarantee at most, one coroutine runs at a time
        if (damageFlash != null)
            StopCoroutine(damageFlash);
        damageFlash = StartCoroutine(DamageFlashing(1f, .1f));
    }
    IEnumerator DamageFlashing(float duration, float interval) {
        int index = 0;
        //var is a replacement for WaitForSeconds bc it would be redundant
        var wait = new WaitForSeconds(interval);
        for (float elapsedTime = 0; elapsedTime < duration; elapsedTime += interval) {
            //divides the index by 2 and returns the remainder
            sr.color = colors[index % 2];
            index++;
            //waits the interval time and then continues the next color in the flashing duration
            yield return wait;
        }
        damageFlash = null;
    }
}
```

```
public class Enemy : Character {
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask player;
    protected override void Start() {
        maxHealth = 3;
        base.Start();
    }
    protected override void Update() {
        base.Update();
        //if (CanTakeDamage()) {
        //    if (Physics2D.OverlapArea(recieveDamageCheckP1.position, recieveDamageCheckP2.position, player)) {
        //        TakeDamage(1);
        //        Debug.Log("Enemy taking damage");
        //    }
        //}
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
        //if(collision.layer)
    }
    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other) {
        if (other.TryGetComponent(out Player player)) {
            if (CanTakeDamage()) {
                TakeDamage(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried using OnCollisionEnter and OnTriggerEnter with colliders as well as the OverlapArea method. I've watched hours of tutorials and for my specific project, I'm having trouble.

Comment: deep inheritance-chains are not neccessarily a bad thing, as long as your classes really **are** of the base-type. When however you just inherit to have access to the base-class-members, then composition is your way to go. Having said this I can't see anything inherently whrong with your code: having an `Enemy`-class that *is* a `Character` makes totally sense, from my perspective. In contrast an `Enemy` *having* a `Character` seems somewhat unnatural to me.

Comment: Absolutely agree with MakePeace. It's a rule of thumb, "composition over inheritance" - not a "never do it". Like many other "rules" in coding.

Comment: C# doesn't have multi-inheritance in classes, so composition is the only way right now to make an "Enemy" out of something not "Character". For example in Fallout 2 you can attack doors, which obviously not a Character with skill/perks and dialogues. Or steal from chest which is not a character too, but rather connected to some character by other means (traders for example). So, I pretty much always use composition. Just to be able refactor this easily. It will happen eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deep inheritance-chains are not neccessarily a bad thing, as long as your classes really **are** of the base-type. When however you just inherit to have access to the base-class-members, then composition is your way to go. Having said this I can't see anything inherently whrong with your code: having an `Enemy`-class that *is* a `Character` makes totally sense, from my perspective. In contrast an `Enemy` *having* a `Character` seems somewhat unnatural to me. On the other hand an `Enemy` **has** some attacks. It makes no sense to argue an `Enemy`**being** a list of attacks.

A box of apples however *might* be a list of apples. However chances are you're better of making a box *having* a list of apples internally and then only expose those members you really *want* to expose to the outside. In particular you probably don't want to expose index-based access to the items in the underlying list, e.g. this seems odd:

```
Box<Apple> b = new Box<Apple>(10);
b[0] = new Apple();
```

In fact what you mention is  like Fildor correctly mentions - more of a rule of thumb. In particular it is *favour* composition over inhertance. That implies that there are circumstances where inheritance is absolutely the correct way, and some where composition is better.